# What are the most common web analytics strategies and best practices?

Tags: analytics

I've recently been working on analytics for a website with a relatively large and growing database. I would like to track events and other information, and display them in a comprehensive manner. I'm new to web analytics, and am wondering what best practices and strategies are commonly used to solve these problems?

(Note: this information is meant to supplement information from another tool like google analytics or mixpanel.)